# node.js post base64 "value" is out of bounds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a upload Image api using Node.js.
If I post a base64 string with 3kb, works fine.
But if I post a string up to 300kb or more, it shows:

> TypeError: "value" argument is out of bounds
>       at checkInt (buffer.js:1178:11)
>       at Buffer.writeUInt16LE (buffer.js:1236:5)
>       at WritableTrackingBuffer.writeUInt16LE (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/tedious/lib/tracking-buffer/writable-tracking-buffer.js:87:19)
>       at WritableTrackingBuffer.writeUsVarbyte (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/tedious/lib/tracking-buffer/writable-tracking-buffer.js:243:12)
>       at Object.writeParameterData (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js:942:25)
>       at new RpcRequestPayload (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/tedious/lib/rpcrequest-payload.js:95:12)
>       at Connection.callProcedure (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:961:58)
>       at parent.acquire (/Users/usr/Desktop/Money/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:1022:20)

Here is my api code, I'm using the 'fs', 'js-base64' module.
I have already tried google it, but can't find any solutions.

```
var base64Data = tmp.base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
fs.writeFile('img/'+Name, base64Data, 'base64', 
function(err) {
   if(err) {
   res.send(err); 
           }  
   else
 {
   res.send('okay');
 }
});
```

Comment: I suggest debugging - I think your issue is here https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/7727b5aa06e8ee2befed565b73d6a7d0a5fb9b31/src/tracking-buffer/writable-tracking-buffer.js#L209

Comment: - specifically, I am guessing 16 bits is not enough to hold the "length" and the tedious.js developers are making the assumption that it would be?